# Put request failed : INSERT INTO "PARTITION_PARAMS" when executing an insert..select query with hundreds of fields

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

Executing an insert..select query over Tez on a Hortonworks HDP 3 cluster with hive3, I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. MetaException(message:
Put request failed : INSERT INTO "PARTITION_PARAMS" ("PARAM_VALUE","PART_ID","PARAM_KEY") VALUES (?,?,?) )
```

The destination table has 200 fields and it is partitioned by two fields. Performing some testing, the error dissapears when the destination table has 143 fields. If I change the names of destination table fields with shorter ones, I can get the query working without error with more fields, but I can't get it working with the 200 fields I need.

Hive Metastore is configured to use a PostgreSQL database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We where hitting [HIVE-20221](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-20221)

We can get the query executing correctly, setting `hive.stats.autogather=false`